# Operation could not be completed (error 0x00000002) while using rundll32

Tags: windows, printing, driver

I came across this issue (I'm using windows 7 64x). I'm running this command `RUNDLL32.EXE PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /ia /m "Printer" /f "C:\Program Files (x86)\Project\bin\drivers\Print\printer.inf` and it gives me error saying `Operation could not be completed (error 0x00000002)` I've searched around and found few solutions, like restarting `Print Spooler` and etc. But none of them worked for me, So I've searched and error `0x00000002` means `The system cannot find the file specified.` I've opened and inf file which looks like this:

```
[Version]
Signature="$Windows NT$"
Provider="Ukve"
ClassGUID={4D36E979-D525-7CE-BLC1-08002BE10318}
Class=Printer
CatalogFile=printer.cat
DriverVer=03/26/2015,6
DriverPackageDisplayName="Printer Adapter"

[Manufacturer]
"Ukve" = printer, NTamd64

[printer]
"Ukve Printer" = printer.gpd, printer

[printer.NTamd64]
"Printer" = printer.gpd, printer

[printer.gpd]
CopyFiles=@printer.gpd
DataSection=UNIDRV_DATA
Include=NTPRINT.INF
Needs=UNIDRV.OEM,TTFSUB.OEM

[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir=66000

[SourceDisksNames]
1 = "Printer Disk"

[SourceDisksFiles]
printer.gpd = 1
```

I can see that `printer.gpd` file is in same directory with the printer security catalog. My question is depending on this, what files could be missing? Hope you can hep, thanks.

Comment: Are you using any co-installer? Is there any file generated with your .sys file called Wdfcoinstalle010xx.dll?